# Tools for viewing logs of unlimited size

Tags: language-agnostic, logging, large-files, system-administration

It's no secret that application logs can go well beyond the limits of naive log viewers, and the desired viewer functionality (say, filtering the log based on a condition, or highlighting particular message types, or splitting it into sublogs based on a field value, or merging several logs based on a time axis, or bookmarking etc.) is beyond the abilities of large-file text viewers.

I wonder:

- Whether decent specialized applications exist (I haven't found any)
- What functionality might one expect from such an application? (I'm asking because my student is writing such an application, and the functionality above has already been implemented to a certain extent of usability)

Comment: what's wrong with `tail` :-) ?

Comment: Interesting.  Based on the question, I can conclude that jkff uses Windows. :-)

Comment: I use Windows indeed, but while I was using Linux for a long time, the functionality of textutils was not always enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Log Expert](http://www.log-expert.de/) lately.

[alt text http://www.log-expert.de/images/stories/logexpertshowcard.gif](http://www.log-expert.de/images/stories/logexpertshowcard.gif)

I can take a while to load large files, but it will in fact load them. I couldn't find the file size limit (if there is any) on the site, but just to test it, I loaded a 300mb log file, so it can at least go that high.

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting even in the case if it can't handle files at the scale of gigabytes. At least we can steal some of its features ;)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Commander has a built-in program called Lister which works very quickly for any file size. I've used it with GBs worth of log files without a problem.

http://www.ghisler.com/lister/

A slightly more powerful tool I sometimes use it Universal Viewer from http://www.uvviewsoft.com/.